# jQuery Mobile popups/notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, razor

I want to create a small popup/notification that will occur when values change in my database. the logic is being passed correctly. However, I'm not sure how to make the popups occur properly and at all as well.

I have two buttons:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red" data-rel="popup"   data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_CS" style="pointer-events: none;">CS</a>    
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red" data-rel="popup"   data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_GH" style="pointer-events: none;">GH</a>
```

I would like to have the notifications pop up a little bit above these buttons. This is what I have created but I just haven't positioned them yet:

```
<div id="GH_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> GH is OFF! </p>
</div>

<div id="CS_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> CS is OFF! </p>
</div>
```

I also have some Javascript that determines when these notifications will pop up:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () { GrabGhCsStatus(); });

    function GrabGhCsStatus() {
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","GhCsStatus"))';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
        if (data.CheckIfCsIsRunning == 1 && data.CheckIfGhIsRunning == 0) {
            $("#GH_popup").popup();
            $("#GhCsStatus_GH").remove();
            if (data.CsStatus == 0) {
                $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Red' });
            } else {
                $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Green' });
            }
        }
     }
        ...
        ...
        ...
  </script>
```

I feel as though I am putting the jQuery popup attributes in the wrong areas and that I am not using them properly =/

Comment: First off, don't use .ready() in JQM. What do you get when you click the button? Popups show or not?

Comment: I do not want to click anything for popups to show. I just want it to show whenever the logic in GrabGhCsStatus() occurs. No popups show as well

Comment: To show a popup `$('#id').popup('open');`, that's it.

Comment: @Omar that did the trick! thanks! you can write it as an answer and I'll submit it as an answer!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck on your project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a popup programmatically, use this code

```
$('#popup_id').popup('open');
```

To close it

```
$('#popup_id').popup('close');
```

[Popup widget API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/)